# How can I select and navigate to last row in grid when open Interactive grid?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

How can I navigate to last line when open the interactive grid in oracle apex

and when click Add Row button add new line after last line in the Interactive grid ?

```
I turned off Select first row option but still when click add Row new row created on first line not last line in the grid
```

Can I do it by java script code also in Java script Execute when Page Loads ?

[image]

Any Idea please ?